# are there are public services which can translate text to a date?

Tags: text-processing

example
"this tuesday" should return "25 August 2020"
"first tuesday of september" should return 1 September 2020"?

Google search page does it but do they have an api to do this?

Comment: "they" is ambiguous. Tag your question with the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [dateparser.io](https://dateparser.io) is what you need.

They offer a free option with 50,000 requests per month.

From their website:

> "There is a wide range of ways to express a date in comparison to the
> current day. **Expressions like 2 months from now or last Sunday are no
> problem.** Explore our full documentation to see the numerous
> expressions that are supported."

They support [**relative dates**](https://dateparser.io/documentation.html) (from the bottom of the page):

```
today   - 2020-08-23
yesterday -     2020-08-22
last friday  - 2020-08-21
next week - 2020-08-30
last month  - 2020-07-23
in 5 days   - 2020-08-28
fifteen years ago   - 2005-08-23
a day from now  - 2020-08-24
5 months before now  - 2020-03-23
```

Comment: thanks I'll give them a try when they fix their free plan sign up page :(

Comment: Okay. You might want to send them an email: https://dateparser.io/contact.html